# How to make the primary key as varchar

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Hi guys so i dont know how to make it as varchar because is want to input BSIT as my primary key and i cant figure it out how to make it as characters please help me this is my code btw

```
create table CourseTBL
(
    CourseID int primary key,
    Course varchar(50),
    Description varchar(50),
)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's usually better to use an `INT` as the primary key. Do you just want to make `Course` unique?

Comment: @Barmar I want to make it as an character code not numbers and I don't know how to do it. It's my project requirement and I can't figure it out how to make it as char.

Comment: `CourseID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @Barmar I tried that too but doesn't work

Comment: you have tags for both MySQL and T-SQL. Which are you actually using? Remove the other tag.

Comment: Add what you tried and the error message to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to create a different `CODE` column to use `WHERE` condition on it, because key is something meaningless and is intended for referential integrity only. For PK add a constraint as an another element of `CREATE TABLE` statement. [Like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a8adfef472384ce0ea19900747cbf068):

```
create table CourseTBL
(
    CourseID varchar(50),
    Course varchar(50),
    Description varchar(50),
    primary key( CourseID )
)
```

Comment: MySQL allows you to add a primary key either as an option on the column or as a constraint later. This shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: yes :( not working tried your code but still doesn't work

Comment: A primary key's purpose is to uniquely identify a row. It is fine to be a varchar/etc if it a natural or meaningful key, especially if sorting by it can be useful. Having a key as a separate number (e.g., an auto-incrementing int) is called a 'surrogate' or 'convenience' key as it's a special kind of key - one in which you offload the references to the new key. For example, say you have a 'reporting by day' table. Why not have the PK as the date? Adding a separate PK just bloats your table and you should still put a unique constraint on the date field, as well as the clustered index.

Comment: @seanb Yes, it's not very precise statement. It is not a rule of thumb of course. But when you put an intelligence in primary key, you will protect your model against changes. If on some day you'll find that you need to identify your entity by any additional attribute (because of any reason), and your varchar is not long enough, you will break an intelligence of a key or break it's meaning or will update all your related tables and hope that you didn't miss anything. For date example I really cannot imagine a date to be a primary key of any entity except calendar.

Comment: @Jujubreatz "doesn't work" isn't a useful question. Do you get an error? If so, what is the exact error message? And you still haven't clarified whether you're using MySQL or SQL-Server.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to add course code column

```
Create table CourseTBL
(
    CourseID int primary key,
    CourseName varchar(50),
    CourseCode varchar(10),
    CourseDescription varchar(50),
)
```